# Spring Security aren't reading my login credencials from database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I recently start a spring project which make use from spring security and hibernate to implement access control to the project. (the source code of application is available here: https://github.com/klebermo/webapp1).

My problem is that the system isn't reading the login credencials from database. I can assure the problem isn't related to permissions in the database, since the Hibernate can create and update the tables (in fact, I start the application with an empty database, and all tables were created by the system).

Someone can find any problem with my code? (the class SecurityConfig and HibernateConfig are listed below, for who don't want search for them in the github repository).

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="org.webapp")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource restDataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(restDataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(getUserQuery())
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(getAuthoritiesQuery());
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/spring/erro-login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/spring/index").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/spring/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/spring/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/spring/index").permitAll();
    }

    private String getUserQuery() {
        return "SELECT login as username, senha as password "
                + "FROM usuario "
                + "WHERE login = ?";
    }

    private String getAuthoritiesQuery() {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT usuario.login as username, autorizacao.descricao as authority "
                + "FROM usuario, autorizacao_usuario, autorizacao "
                + "WHERE usuario.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_usuario "
                + "AND autorizacao.id = autorizacao_usuario.fk_autorizacao "
                + "AND usuario.login = ? ";
    }

}
```

**HibernateConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.webapp.persistence" })
public class HibernateConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.webapp.persistence.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassname"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
      dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop `@Autowired` from the first `configure` method (as you can see in [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) guide it should not be present)

Comment: Ok, I fix that (by the way, silly mistake mine). But still happening the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have configured Hiernate, but for retrieving user database, you are using simple JDBC datasource.

If you want to configure Spring Web Security based on Hibernate User database, you may have to have dao created for quering user and user roles and creates custom `CustomUserService` by implementing `UserService`.

**Reference:**
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-mvc-security-with-mysql-and-hibernate.html